# Testing views with Spring Framework at the same time you run unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, spring, spring-mvc, view, render

Is there a way to test views rendered in freemarker at the same time I run my unit tests? It would be great if the test failed if Freemarker threw an exception.

Rails has a feature where you can render views whenever an action is called. Is there an easy way to configure this type of behavior for Spring too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://tedyoung.me/2011/02/14/spring-mvc-integration-testing-controllers/) blog post. We used this approach with great success for Velocity template. Looks like [here](http://code.google.com/p/ted-young/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fblog.spring-mvc-integration-testing) is a working code example.

It requires few extra classes like `MockWebApplicationContextLoader` but works great with mocked requests.

Comment: Cool, I will give it a read! This should be IN the framework I think. gotta email them about this as it's just so important I think. Without, you have to manually check every page and every variation of every page... which sucks :/

Comment: Open an [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR) to add the support, I will be the first one to vote for it!